# How do templates avoid infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, rvalue

I am currently following [this tutorial](https://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2014/08/01/postscript-1-easy-cleanup) on SDL2, and have come across templates, which are entirely new to me at this point.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void cleanup(T *t, Args&&... args){
    cleanup(t);
    cleanup(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<> inline void cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *window){
    ...
}
...
```

I don't understand how calling `cleanup()` in the `cleanup()` function doesn't just create an endless recursion cycle, and instead calls one of the specialized template functions below. Also, I can't make much sense of calling `forward()` for `a` but not for `b`, as for what I've gathered, `forward()` should fix any problems when calling `cleanup()` with either lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: Well for one the arguments of `cleanup(T *t, Args&&... args)` are different than `cleanup<SDL_Window>(SDL_Window *window)`, the former taking an argument of type `T` and a variable number of arguments for `typename... Args`. Note that `typename... Args` still requires at least one argument, so there is no ambiguity between your template cleanup function and the resolved explicit ones.

Comment: templated types are translated to specific functions/classes at compile time. for variadic templates, writing "recursions" is common practice. you can read the first part of [this tutorial](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/) to figure out why it's technically not recursion

Comment: @h0r53: `typename... Args` does not require at least one argument, it can match zero.  But it's a worse match than pretty much anything else, due to overloading rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cleanup(T *a, Vars&&... b)
```

If you passed `n` vars to this function, the first one would go tho the first function in the body (which ends. note that there is no inner calls).

And the rest `n-1` would go to the second function in the body and this would call a function again but using `n-1` vars.

This process would continue until having only two parameters and then both first and second calls would use the second function because it would be the best match.

Hence this is not endless function.

Comment: "cleanup() in the cleanup function doesn't just create and endless recursion cycle and instead calls one of the specialized template functions below."  I think a key piece here is the operator overloading rules making all the other methods better matches for the 1 argument forms.

Comment: Re: "the second wouldn't be called because the parameter pack would be empty": I don't think that's a correct explanation. An empty parameter pack is valid -- but in this case it would cause a compile-error rather than infinite recursion, because there's no zero-arg `cleanup()`. (If you were to create a zero-arg `cleanup()` and then write `cleanup(foo)` where `foo` has some type that there's no specialization for, then you will indeed get infinite recursion!)